# How to implement an iterator/container that is standards-compliant?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11

Suppose I have an abstract container-like class called `RuleBook`. Users of `RuleBook` expect to be able to forward-iterate over the `RuleBook` to obtain `Rule`s.

Unlike standard containers, there will be no restrictions on the memory layout of the the concrete subclasses here.  Instead, it is up to the implementers of the subclasses to comply with the forward-iteration requirement of `RuleBook` and satisfy this requirement based on its own data structures.

I am thinking that `RuleBook` should contain pure virtual `begin()` and `end()` so it would work with **range-based for**, but I am running into a few problems.

*What should the signatures be for begin() and end()?  How should BasketballRules and CompanyRules be implemented?*

*How do we deal with the end condition when the iterator goes past the last item?*

In the example below, you can assume that `m_rp` and `m_rpp` only point to one Rule each.  We want to return some kind of iterator for the guts (like a `Rule*`).  We can also assume that all subclasses of Foo will contain `Rule` in various data structures, which will be up to the whim of the implementor.

If I implement the entire thing using `Rule*` as my iterator and `null_ptr` as my beyond-the-endpoint, would this be STL compliant?

I am currently looking into custom iterators, but I'm not even sure this problem fits well with that paradigm because each subclass must effectively define the guts of the iteration.

**CODE**

```
struct RuleBook
{
  // virtual Rule* begin() = 0;
  // virtual Rule* end() = 0; 
};

struct CompanyRules :
    public RuleBook
{
    Rule m_r;
};

struct BasketballRules :
    public RuleBook
{
    // return the three Rules, one-at-a-time, in succession
    Rule   m_r;
    Rule*  m_rp;
    Rule** m_rpp;
};

int
main( int argv, char* argc[] )
{
}
```

Comment: The wording of this sounds very much like a school homework. You are looking for the site called "www.scholehomeworkdoneforcash.com" which isn't here...

Comment: @MatsPetersson no need to be snide or condescending if you don't feel like answering - the last time I was officially in school was a long time ago

Comment: @kfmfe04: I don't know where such a class would be useful. How would one use `begin()` and `end()` functions to do anything useful?

Comment: @Nawaz for range-based for - I have containers that I need to access to, but how the guts are arranged is of no consequence to the caller.  Hence, I would like to have a common interface.  Specifically, it's part of an Abstract Syntax Tree that I've parsed as part of a DSL - the caller doesn't need to know the details.

Comment: The reason I'm snide is that you are trying to learn something. You need to show us that you are at least trying, not just post your homework on some website and hope to get a solution.

Comment: @MatsPetersson well, I can write a pointer-based solution to my question, but that doesn't help anything (I'm 42 - the last time I was in school was almost 2 decades ago) - that would obfuscate the problem.  My issue is, I don't understand the complexities of compliance to STL iterators.  Perhaps you would be happier if I had reworded my question?  Perhaps I misunderstood - SO isn't for asking question to learn something?

Comment: @kfmfe04: Please come up with a good example where such a class with `begin()` and `end()` to iterate over **seemingly unrelated members** would be useful. The users of class must know what he/she is iterating over, so the details are necessary.

Comment: @Nawaz ok - I will reword my symbols from Foo if that helps - ty for your constructive comments.

Comment: SO is definitely for asking and learning. But your question is very much formulated like the typical "I want someonez to write my codez".

Comment: @MatsPetersson I apologize for my abstractions - I have reworded the OP

Comment: @kfmfe04: Now that looks a bit better. Now if all the members are `Rule`, then why declare three different members? Why not just ONE, preferably `std::vector<Rule>`?

Comment: @Nawaz because I want to leave that totally up to the implementor of `BaskeballRules` - perhaps there is a special set of rules for Christmas day - I don't know.  All I need is an implementation of begin() and end() which will let me forward iterate over all the Rules for that concrete class.  I know this will look a bit different depending on each concrete class, that's why I didn't list too many different possibilities (didn't want to clutter the question too much).  As a caller of RuleBook, all I need to know is that I can forward-iterate over your Rules.

Comment: OK, so I would look at a bit of pointer and casting "fun".

Comment: @kfmfe04: Iterators work over a container. Where's your container defined? You need to know 3 things at least: a) size of each item; b) where the container begins; c) current number of items (or alternatively, know where the container ends);

Comment: @jweyrich there is no concrete container.  You may think of `RuleBook` as a forward-iteratable container of Rules in the abstract.  It is up to the concrete subclasses to define what that ordering means, but they should comply with that requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're really looking for general usage, or allowing the utterly arbitrary definition of `iterator` to bring this home. in C++11 there is a *tremendous* set of utilities that are there for the exploiting in `<iterator_traits>` and `<iterator>` which you will likely find valuable in your quest. They certainly were in mine when I had to write a template class that accepted an arbitrary `template< class Iterator >` solution to a not-so-trivial problem. Look into them.

Comment: @WhozCraig +1 fwiw, I think this is going to be a one-off for me.  I will look into those C++11 features you mentioned.  ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be difficult to get right.

> What should the signatures be for begin() and end()?

There's not much choice, they pretty much have to be something like

```
RuleBook::iterator begin();
RuleBook::iterator end();
```

(Adding `const` overloads if desired)

> How should BasketballRules and CompanyRules be implemented?

Carefully :)

> How do we deal with the end condition when the iterator goes past the last item?

You design your iterator types correctly so it Just Works.  You need an iterator type that can be compared for equality and can be incremented. When you have an iterator to the last item in a container and you increment it, it must become equal to the past-the-end iterator.

> If I implement the entire thing using Rule* as my iterator and null_ptr as my beyond-the-endpoint, would this be STL compliant?

No.  If your iterator type is just `Rule*` then incrementing an iterator doesn't move to the next `Rule`, it just points to the next location in memory, which might not even be a `Rule` object, leading to undefined behaviour.  e.g. for `BasketballRules` if you have `Rule*` pointing to `m_r` and you increment it you are not pointing to a valid `Rule` object you're pointing to the memory occupied by `m_rp` i.e. a `Rule*` and dereferencing it is undefined behaviour.

Also, if you keep incrementing a `Rule*` you never reach the past-the-end `nullptr` value.

I gave Yakk's answer an upvote because it is a plausible implementation, but it would be hard to get right.  There are lots of things to consider and include in the polymorphic interface e.g. what happens if you use `==` to compare two `RuleBook::iterator` objects where one points to a `CompanyRules` and one points to a `BasketballRules`, how does equality work for polymorphic iterators?

What happens if you assign the iterator to the `BasketballRules` object to an iterator to a `CompanyRules` object? You need a "deep copy" for the polymorphic types.

You'd need a different derived iterator-impl type for each container, the iterator type for `CompanyRule` containers needs to know everything about the `CompanyRule` type, and so on for every derived container type. Each of those concrete iterator-impl types needs to implement almost the entire iterator interface as virtual functions.  The difficulty of implementing it indicates a problem with the design.

A simpler design would be for each derived container type to manage an actual physical container of the same type.  The code specific to each derived container consists of just updating the contents of the list whenever the derived object's contents change. The iterator types are then straightforward and non-polymorphic e.g.

```
struct RuleBook
{
  typedef std::vector<Rule*> list_type;
  typedef list_type::iterator iterator;

  virtual iterator begin() = 0;
  virtual iterator end() = 0;
};

struct CompanyRules :
    public RuleBook
{
    CompanyRules() : m_list{ &m_r } { }
    Rule m_r;

    iterator begin() { return m_list.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return m_list.end(); }

private:
    list_type m_list;
};

struct BasketballRules :
    public RuleBook
{
    BaseketballRules() : m_list{ &m_r, m_rp, *m_rpp } { }

    // return the three Rules, one-at-a-time, in succession
    Rule   m_r;
    Rule*  m_rp;
    Rule** m_rpp;

    iterator begin() { return m_list.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return m_list.end(); }

private:
    // N.B.
    // must update m_list[1] any time m_rp changes
    // must update m_list[2] any time the pointee of m_rpp changes (harder!)
    list_type m_list;
};
```

Comment: +1 fantastic - ty for a well-thought-out answer with working code... ...I will try it out

Answer (score 1):

The exact signatures don't matter because range-based for-loops are defined in terms of the expression used. If `begin` or `end` member functions are found then they are called like `__range.begin()` and `__range.end()`. An example of the signature not mattering is that these member functions could have any number and type of parameters as long as they can be called like `.begin()` and `.end()` (which means the parameters must have default values).

If the type does not have `begin` and `end` member functions then the expressions `begin(__range)` and `end(__range)` are used. (where `__range` is `auto &&__range` initialized with the expression you use in the range-for-loop). So again the exact signature does matter as long as the argument dependent lookup works.

---

> How should BasketballRules and CompanyRules be implemented?
>
> How do we deal with the end condition when the iterator goes past the last item?

These are separate questions from how range-base-for-loops work. You should ask other questions about these specifically.

But if you use pointers as your iterators then using `nullptr` as the end iterator would not be appropriate because incrementing the last valid pointer would not give you a null pointer; it would give you a pointer one past the end of the range. Also if you use `Rule*` as your iterator then you're not leaving the implementation up to the container class; the container will have to maintain a contiguous array of Rules.

Comment: +1 ty for your useful comments - I am looking into your points and into how `iterator`s are constructed - perhaps I need to write my own custom iterator here.

Answer (score 1):

Boost has some iterator helper template classes -- crtp that require you to implement a handful of methods.  A `pImpl` based user of them would allow compliant and virtual behavior for your iterators.  Ie, the `pImpl` is a pure virtual abstract class which the iterator delegates its work to.

Write a pure virtual `pImpl` iterator.  That is the return type of `begin` and `end`.  Child classes make instances of the iterator with concrete `pImpl` instances, custom written for how the data is stored.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try something like the way Alex Allain explains over [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html) in his tutorial about range-based for loops. It also has an example for making a data structure that is iterable by a range-based for loop

The things that are required are

1. a .begin() and a .end() method. They can be standalone as well.
2. operator!= , ++ and * overloading so that iterator operations that need to be performed     are supported.